# How to set Spring Boot properties with SpringApplicationBuilder overwriting those from profile files?

Tags: spring-boot

Given is a Spring Boot application with a standard `application.yml` profile file containing custom properties like that:

```yaml
application.name: I am Universe
```

I now want to read in a `config.ini` to overwrite some of these properties. The ini may look like that:

```
name=Master, the name is Master
```

So let's say I end up with a `Map<String, String>` which I somehow have to add to the `SpringApplicationBuilder` so that Spring Boot can initialize its environment context fully configured during the startup phase and has these additional properties in place at the time when the `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` gets dispatched.

The following attempt (property hardcoded for tryout) unfortunately doesn't apply the ini-properties with highest precedence but only as default ones:

```java
new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
        .properties("application.name=Master, the name is Master")
        .run(args);
```

What is the correct way to provide properties programmatically during Spring Boot's startup phase with highest precedence?